# Ubuntu Crash then black screen

Tags: crash

Screen went black, with @^@^@^@^@^@ appearing in the upper left corner for a few seconds, then disappearing, only to leave a cursor. At this point it was unresponsive.

Any ideas what this might mean?

Running Ubuntu 22.04 on an older Asus ROG laptop

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: yeah - it restarted fine, just wondering if anyone's experienced this specifically, and what the cause may be

Comment: Also, does the issue appear repeatedly? Does it happen when you open a certain program?